# Magento 2.4-develop - reCAPTCHA is not supported?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, recaptcha, google-recaptcha

We are using Magento ver. dev-2.4-develop

Our security scan recommends to allow google reCAPTCHA

But there is not any option in our admin panel to enable it.

As guide says we should have same options in admin panel to enable it but seems our magento does not supports google recaptcha at all.

How we can appear it?

[image]

Please help!

Here are listed all modules of my magento

```
Magento_AdminAnalytics
Magento_Store
Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport
Magento_Directory
Magento_Amqp
Magento_AmqpStore
Magento_Config
Magento_Theme
Magento_Atttosum
Magento_Backend
Magento_Search
Magento_Backup
Magento_Variable
Magento_Eav
Magento_BundleImportExport
Magento_CacheInvalidate
Magento_Customer
Magento_AdminNotification
Magento_Indexer
Magento_Security
Magento_Authorization
Magento_GraphQl
Magento_Cms
Magento_CatalogImportExport
Magento_Catalog
Magento_CatalogInventory
Magento_Rule
Magento_Payment
Magento_CatalogRuleGraphQl
Magento_CatalogRule
Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite
Magento_StoreGraphQl
Magento_Widget
Magento_Quote
Magento_SalesSequence
Magento_CheckoutAgreementsGraphQl
Magento_CmsGraphQl
Magento_EavGraphQl
Magento_CmsUrlRewrite
Magento_CmsUrlRewriteGraphQl
Magento_User
Magento_Msrp
Magento_Sales
Magento_CatalogGraphQl
Magento_Checkout
Magento_Contact
Magento_Cookie
Magento_Cron
Magento_Csp
Magento_CurrencySymbol
Magento_Captcha
Magento_Integration
Magento_Downloadable
Magento_CustomerGraphQl
Magento_CustomerImportExport
Magento_Deploy
Magento_Developer
Magento_Dhl
Magento_AsynchronousOperations
Magento_DirectoryGraphQl
Magento_QuoteGraphQl
Magento_DownloadableGraphQl
Magento_ImportExport
Magento_ConfigurableProduct
Magento_CatalogCustomerGraphQl
Magento_CatalogSearch
Magento_AdvancedSearch
Magento_Elasticsearch
Magento_Email
Magento_EncryptionKey
Magento_Fedex
Magento_GiftMessage
Magento_GiftMessageGraphQl
Magento_GoogleAdwords
Magento_GoogleAnalytics
Magento_Ui
Magento_BundleGraphQl
Magento_PageCache
Magento_GroupedProduct
Magento_GroupedImportExport
Magento_GroupedCatalogInventory
Magento_GroupedProductGraphQl
Magento_DownloadableImportExport
Magento_Bundle
Magento_InstantPurchase
Magento_Analytics
Magento_LayeredNavigation
Magento_LoginAsCustomer
Magento_LoginAsCustomerAdminUi
Magento_LoginAsCustomerApi
Magento_LoginAsCustomerAssistance
Magento_LoginAsCustomerFrontendUi
Magento_LoginAsCustomerLog
Magento_LoginAsCustomerPageCache
Magento_LoginAsCustomerQuote
Magento_LoginAsCustomerSales
Magento_Marketplace
Magento_MediaContent
Magento_MediaContentApi
Magento_MediaContentCatalog
Magento_MediaContentCms
Magento_MediaContentSynchronization
Magento_MediaContentSynchronizationApi
Magento_MediaContentSynchronizationCatalog
Magento_MediaContentSynchronizationCms
Magento_MediaGallery
Magento_MediaGalleryApi
Magento_MediaGalleryCatalog
Magento_MediaGalleryCatalogIntegration
Magento_MediaGalleryCatalogUi
Magento_MediaGalleryCmsUi
Magento_MediaGalleryIntegration
Magento_MediaGalleryMetadata
Magento_MediaGalleryMetadataApi
Magento_MediaGalleryRenditions
Magento_MediaGalleryRenditionsApi
Magento_MediaGallerySynchronization
Magento_MediaGallerySynchronizationApi
Magento_MediaGallerySynchronizationMetadata
Magento_MediaGalleryUi
Magento_MediaGalleryUiApi
Magento_MediaStorage
Magento_MessageQueue
Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable
Magento_MsrpConfigurableProduct
Magento_MsrpGroupedProduct
Magento_Multishipping
Magento_MysqlMq
Magento_NewRelicReporting
Magento_Newsletter
Magento_NewsletterGraphQl
Magento_OfflinePayments
Magento_SalesRule
Magento_GraphQlCache
Magento_CardinalCommerce
Magento_Vault
Magento_Paypal
Magento_PaypalGraphQl
Magento_Persistent
Magento_ProductAlert
Magento_ProductVideo
Magento_CheckoutAgreements
Magento_QuoteAnalytics
Magento_QuoteBundleOptions
Magento_QuoteConfigurableOptions
Magento_QuoteDownloadableLinks
Magento_ConfigurableProductGraphQl
Magento_RelatedProductGraphQl
Magento_ReleaseNotification
Magento_Reports
Magento_RequireJs
Magento_Review
Magento_ReviewAnalytics
Magento_ReviewGraphQl
Magento_Robots
Magento_Rss
Magento_Elasticsearch6
Magento_ConfigurableProductSales
Magento_SalesAnalytics
Magento_SalesGraphQl
Magento_SalesInventory
Magento_OfflineShipping
Magento_ConfigurableImportExport
Magento_UrlRewrite
Magento_Elasticsearch7
Magento_CustomerAnalytics
Magento_SendFriend
Magento_SendFriendGraphQl
Magento_Shipping
Magento_Sitemap
Magento_UrlRewriteGraphQl
Magento_CatalogCmsGraphQl
Magento_Webapi
Magento_SwaggerWebapi
Magento_SwaggerWebapiAsync
Magento_Swatches
Magento_SwatchesGraphQl
Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation
Magento_Tax
Magento_TaxGraphQl
Magento_TaxImportExport
Magento_CustomerDownloadableGraphQl
Magento_ThemeGraphQl
Magento_Tinymce3
Magento_Translation
Magento_GoogleOptimizer
Magento_Ups
Magento_SampleData
Magento_CatalogUrlRewriteGraphQl
Magento_CatalogAnalytics
Magento_Usps
Magento_CatalogInventoryGraphQl
Magento_PaypalCaptcha
Magento_VaultGraphQl
Magento_Version
Magento_Swagger
Magento_WebapiAsync
Magento_WebapiSecurity
Magento_Weee
Magento_WeeeGraphQl
Magento_CatalogWidget
Magento_Wishlist
Magento_WishlistAnalytics
Magento_WishlistGraphQl
Amasty_Base
Amasty_CommonTests
Amasty_CronScheduleList
Amasty_ShippingTableRates
Amasty_Xnotif
CommerceExtensions_GuestToReg
Ebizmarts_SagePaySuite
Fooman_EmailAttachments
Fooman_PdfCore
Fooman_PdfDesign
Fooman_PrintOrderPdf
Fooman_PdfCustomiser
Idealpostcodes_Ukaddresssearch
Lof_BasePrice
MageArray_FormBuilder
Magedelight_Base
Magedelight_Storelocator
Magefan_Community
Magefan_Blog
Magefan_WysiwygAdvanced
Magenest_Xero
Mageplaza_Core
Mageplaza_DeleteOrders
Mageplaza_GoogleRecaptcha
Mageplaza_InstagramFeed
Mageplaza_ProductFeed
Magezon_Core
MaxCustomisations_removeCODFrontend
RedChamps_Core
RedChamps_CurrentProductRegistry
RedChamps_SampleProducts
RedChamps_SampleProductsV2
Sparsh_Smtp
Swissup_Core
Swissup_Marketplace
Swissup_SlickCarousel
Swissup_Testimonials
Ulmod_Notificationbar
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find a way to enable reCaptcha if your magento2 has not it as default feature.

You will probably need composer version 1 (version 2 did not worked for me)

1. Enable developer mode

> ```
> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer
> ```

2. Run in your cli

> ```
> composer require msp/recaptcha
> php bin/magento module:enable MSP_ReCaptcha
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> php bin/magento setup:di:compile
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
> php bin/magento cache:flush
> ```

After that you will find a `Security` tab on your site configurations page

Hope it helps someone :)

Comment: This has really helped me. Not sure how and when but MSP_ReCaptcha was removed from our site and BOTS have been insane. Thanks brother!

Answer (score 0):

Normally you find the reCAPTCHA settings in Stores -> Configuration -> Security
[image]

You can also check, if those modules are installed:

```
Magento_ReCaptchaAdminUi
Magento_ReCaptchaCheckout
Magento_ReCaptchaContact
Magento_ReCaptchaCustomer
Magento_ReCaptchaFrontendUi
Magento_ReCaptchaMigration
Magento_ReCaptchaNewsletter
Magento_ReCaptchaPaypal
Magento_ReCaptchaReview
Magento_ReCaptchaSendFriend
Magento_ReCaptchaUi
Magento_ReCaptchaUser
Magento_ReCaptchaValidation
Magento_ReCaptchaValidationApi
Magento_ReCaptchaVersion2Checkbox
Magento_ReCaptchaVersion2Invisible
Magento_ReCaptchaVersion3Invisible
```

by running:

```
bin/magento module:status
```

Comment: Hello. Nope there are not that modules
Above in my question I list all enabled modules.

Comment: That is odd. How did you install magento? Via composer?
Did you check to configure your php.ini to the setting from the documentation?

"Before Google reCAPTCHA can be configured, ensure that your PHP.ini file includes the following setting: allow_url_fopen"

You can find the documentation here:
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/security-google-recaptcha.html

I am using composer for magento and it works pretty well (for the most parts)

Comment: My PHP.ini is OK. And I do not remember how I install. I think composer was only way for it

Comment: did you try to run "composer update" ?

Comment: What is it for? Can it fix recaptcha issue?

Comment: composer is a program to manage dependencies and normally the preferred way to install magento2. "composer update" searches for newer versions of your installed modules and installs them. You can find a bit more infos here: 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/composer.html

Comment: But I have edited magento files in app/design and in app/code
Will it rewrite my changes?

Comment: I would save them just in case - but normally, those files will be kept untouched (the app directory is for exactly that: customization).
Composer updates the things inside the /vendor folder.

Comment: I try that but it did not help, I still do not have google recaptcha option